# phpunit doesn't produce an error if a non-existing function is called

Tags: phpunit

I am trying to learn phpunit while I work on a project, this project requires some files to be copied so I thought I would use vfsStream to mock the filesystem for my unit tests.

as it turns out whenever I include and use the vfsStreamWrapper class, phpunit doesn't seem to care about calling functions that don't exist or any other output for that matter.

the function below I copied over from an example and I changed the second function being called to something I am certain doesn't exist:

```
protected function setUp()
{
    vfsStreamWrapper::register();
    vfsStreamWrapper::yowkes(array('Core' => array('AbstractFactory' => array('test.php'    => 'some text content',
        'other.php'   => 'Some more text content',
        'Invalid.csv' => 'Something else',
    ),
        'AnEmptyFolder'   => array(),
        'badlocation.php' => 'some bad content',
    )
    ));
}
```

All phpunit does is print the following output:

> PHPUnit 3.7.21 by Sebastian Bergmann.

I am running phpunit from a terminal through ssh on a vragant box.

Any help is appreciated.

edit:

```
public function testFilesAreCopiedCorrectly() {

    $remoteDirectory = 'files/remoteFiles/';
    $correctFilePaths = array('20130627-1830-01.xml',
                                '20130627-1830-02.xml',
                                '20130627-1830-03.xml',
                                '20130627-1830-04.xml',
                                '20130627-1830-05.xml',
                                '20130627-1830-06.xml',
                                '20130627-1830-07.xml',
                                '20130627-1830-08.xml',
                                '20130627-1830-09.xml',
                        );

    $remoteImportFileGetter = new RemoteImportFileGetter($remoteDirectory,
                                                        $correctFilePaths,
                                                        vfsStream::url('localDir'));



    $remoteImportFileGetter->copyFilesToLocalDirectory();

    $localFiles = $this->root->getChildren();

    $this->assertCount(9, $localFiles);

    $this->assertEquals($correctFilePaths, $localFiles);

    $i = 0;

    foreach($correctFilePaths as $remoteFile){
        $this->assertEquals(file_get_contents($remoteFile), file_get_contents($localFiles[$i]));
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any actual test? I mean, besides the setUp() function

Comment: Yes I do have a test, I tried this with and without an actual test (one that should pass and one that should fail) but still the same result, no output or error thrown

Comment: Can you show more code?

Comment: I edited the question and added one of the versions of the actual test code

Comment: `All phpunit does is print the following output: ...` Is this *really* all the output?

Comment: other than a blank newline beneath that line it really is all the output

Comment: check your error log.  PHPUnit is crashing probably due to a fatal error in your tests/code.  That is why you are only getting the one line of output and no tests.

Comment: Unfortunally there is not a single warning, error or notice in the apache log.